# Define Transparent Color for a point in a series in VBA

Tags: vba, charts, format

I am trying to define the Transparent color in VBA and apply it to some XY scatter series in VBA. The issue is I have conditioned the points to color based on a `Vlookup` function. The series that is not found in the `Vlookup`, I need to be transparent. I have tried to define the color inside my With statement when looping over the the series. I have tried to assign the Transparency of the series outside the With Statement. Nothing seems to work.

```
'Outside With:
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("contract").Chart
ct = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("contract").Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
Set mysrs = cht.SeriesCollection(ct)
mysrs.Format.Fill.Transparency = 0
mysrs.Format.Line.Transparency = 0

'Inside With:
                lnum = Application.VLookup(mysrs.Name, drng, 2, 0) 'This fails the first instance with G as a Type Mismatch Error.
                On Error GoTo ZZZ
                Select Case lnum
                    Case "G"
                        lColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Case "D"
                        lColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                    Case "M"
                        lColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                    Case "A"
                        lColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End Select

                mysrs.MarkerBackgroundColor = lColor
                mysrs.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                mysrs.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                mysrs.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = lColor
ZZZ:
lColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'this is where I need to define Transparency
```

Comment: Where is  drng defined and assigned? And is lnum declared as variant?

Comment: And why transparent? If not found then don't plot. And do you mean a point on a series or a series?

Comment: If you mean, how do you make a marker fill partially transparent, VBA ignores the `.Format.Fill.Transparency` setting, even if its identical to the macro you just recorded. If you mean, how do I make an unfilled marker (a circle that you can see through), use `.Format.Fill.Visible = False`, and you might want to make the line a bit thicker.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused as to what you are trying to achieve. Not show a point or a series? Transparent or to not plot.

However, your `On Error` is in the wrong place so either place it before the expected error e.g.

```
On Error GoTo ZZZ
lnum = Application.VLookup(mysrs.Name, drng, 2, 0)
```

Or, declare `lnum` as `Variant` and then use `IsError` test on `lnum` e.g.

```
Dim lnum As Variant
lnum = Application.VLookup(mysrs.Name, drng, 2, 0) 

If IsError(lnum) Then
    'Do something
Else
   'Do something else
End If
```

This assumes `drng` is defined as a `Range` object.